# django-rest-auth: What is the email verification for and how can I let the user activate the account correctly?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I might misunderstand something. `django-rest-auth` provides `RegisterView` and an email is supposed to be sent to the user's email after user sign up. However, I've noticed the user is registered with `is_active=True` even before the user confirm the email. Then, what is the email verification for? Do I have to override something and create the user with `is_active=False` when the user register with a site? And if so, how can I achieve it properly? I'm having trouble with it.

Here is what I did.

`urls.py`

```
path('api/v1/rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
```

`serializers.py`

```
from rest_auth.registration.serializers import RegisterSerializer

class CustomRegistrationSerializer(RegisterSerializer):

    def save(self, request):
        user = super(CustomRegistrationSerializer, self).save(request)
        user.is_active = False
        return user
```

`settings.py`

```
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'appname.serializers.CustomRegistrationSerializer',
}
```

and here is an error I encountered.

> File "rest_auth/registration/views.py", line 46, in dispatch
>       return super(RegisterView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
>       response = self.handle_exception(exc)
>
> File "rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
>       self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
>
> File "rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
>       response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "rest_framework/generics.py", line 192, in post
>       return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "rest_auth/registration/views.py", line 65, in create
>       user = self.perform_create(serializer)
>
> File "rest_auth/registration/views.py", line 81, in perform_create
>       None)
>
> File "allauth/account/utils.py", line 183, in complete_signup
>       signal_kwargs=signal_kwargs)
>
> File "/allauth/account/utils.py", line 133, in perform_login
>       return adapter.respond_user_inactive(request, user)
>
> File "allauth/account/adapter.py", line 454, in respond_user_inactive
>       reverse('account_inactive'))
>
> File "django/urls/resolvers.py", line 622, in _reverse_with_prefix
>       raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
>   django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'account_inactive' not found. 'account_inactive' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I'd like to hear how people who are using `django-rest-auth` handle with registration.
Anyone have used `django-rest-auth` and coule give me tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`is_active` is actually not for this purpose. I use it as an admin to deactivate a user when I don't want to delete him. You might want to use `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"` instead:

> ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION (=”optional”)
>
> Determines the e-mail verification method during signup – choose one of `"mandatory"`, `"optional"`, or `"none"`. When set to “mandatory” the user is blocked from logging in until the email address is verified. Choose “optional” or “none” to allow logins with an unverified e-mail address. In case of “optional”, the e-mail verification mail is still sent, whereas in case of “none” no e-mail verification mails are sent.

Source: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html

Many websites required a double opt-in to verify the validity of an email address or for legal purposes and you can accomplish this with quoted setting.

---

Concerning the `NoReverseMatch` exception, you should be able to solve it with following code (but I think you might not need it when you switch to `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"`):

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    ...
]
```

Docs: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

However, you probably don't need this view or want to override it if Django is a backend only. To get an idea how to do that you can look at my [gist](https://gist.github.com/dgilge/dbe9260208aadee535cef7c412a1162e#file-02_adapter-py) where I also override the adapter because there is a URL I don't need.

Comment: completely disagree with the first part of your answer. is_active should fill exactly that purpose. If you don't use it there is simply no piece of state or db record indicating if a user as verified their mail or not.

Comment: ```is_active``` field is more than just an email verification confirmation flag it's part of ```django.contrib.auth```. I would add my own custom ```is_email_verified``` field instead and set it to True on ```email_confirmed``` signal or use django-allauth's ```EmailAddress.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, verified=True).exists()``` check in the view.

Answer (score 0):

django rest auth handles email by using an extra table that have email accounts and a flag if they are verified or not..

It has taken this from [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).